# What is the fastest way to compare alternate characters of a string using java?

Tags: java, string, performance, character

There are multiple strings being passed to this program from standard input. The first int input T, is the number of test cases(Strings) being passed to this program. A string which has different alternate characters is perfect. If alternate characters are the same, you have need to delete 1 of those two characters. Basically, you have to count, how many characters, do you need to delete to get a perfect String? For example: ABABAB is pefect while AABABAA is not perfect. You need to delete 2 A's, the first one and the last one.In AAAA, you need to delete 3 A's to get a perfect string. String input can be very large. What is the fastest way to count number of such deletion?  The code below, written by me, is working very slow.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int T= scan.nextInt();
    String str;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
        str=scan.next();
        for(int j=0; j<str.length()-1; j++){
            if(str.charAt(j)!=str.charAt(j+1)){
                j+=2;
            }
            else{
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: It even doesn't compile

Comment: @Andremoniy Hello, Please try now. It will get compiled.

Comment: Unclear, what is the first int input?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, The first int input T, is  the number of test cases being passed to this program.

Comment: The fact that you edit you source code all the time, first posting something that doesn't compile and then something that doesn't terminate, suggests thay you are typing in the code here by hand. Please copy-paste working code from the program you wrote (e.g. directly from your IDE). Also make sure the indenting of your code reflects the code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code after eliminating all the logical errors. For some test cases its execution time is up to 0.45-0.50 seconds. Can its performance be improved?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int T=0; String str;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    T=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<T; i++){
       str= sc.next();
       solve(str);
    }
}
public static void solve(String str){
    char first, second; int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length()-1; i++){
       first= str.charAt(i);
       second= str.charAt(i+1);
       if(first==second){
           count++;
       }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you worry about the performance, worry about whether your solution is correct. For the input ABAAB, your program returns 0, however 1 A must be removed to obtain a perfect string.

Then: what do you mean with "very large". How many characters is that? And what is "very slow"?

You will have to look at every character of the string at least once, so you will not get much faster. However, you might be able to optimize a bit. At the moment, it is possible that you look at a single character *twice* (once in `str.charAt(j+1)` and in the next iteration in `str.charAt(j)`). It is certainly possible to write your algorithm in such a way that every character of the string is visited *exactly once*. But again, you should focus on correctness before you focus on speed.

Comment: Hey @Hoopje Thanks! I was having input of size 10^10. There was one logical mistake in the above section of code. But still some test cases were  slow after correction.